# How to create windows .exe on linux OS with quarkus native

Tags: maven, native, quarkus, quarkus-native

I want to build windows executable on linux OS(ubuntu) using quarkus native.
When i build on Linux it creates "app-runner" and when i build it on Windows it is "app-runner.exe"

It creates problem where i have to switch to certain OS to release proper build

I installed GraalVM for Java 17 and i use this command for building

note: i skip tests to reduce total build time

```
mvn clean install -Dnative -DskipTests -Dquarkus.profile=dev
```

I looked in quarkus guides but i couldn't find any relevant information about this problem.

Comment: With Graal you have to build on target OS to get a native compiled executable for the appropriate OS..you can not cross build as far as I know. (https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/407 and https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/2931 )

Comment: I dont think building exe in linux is possible but you can use github  to build windows exe. here is an example for building in windows in github https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/swaggerific/blob/main/.github/workflows/windows.yml